# vary controller based upon device

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working with an MVC4 web application that has 3 snap points - desktop, phone and tablet.

I have set up the display modes so a view varies based upon the device accessing the site. I am also using media queries and jquery mobile to assist with mobile development of the site.

When the site is being accessed from a phone, less database stored data is shown to the end user. For this reason, the heavy processing on the controller isnt needed for phones.

Is there any elegant way to vary the controller used or the action method when the consuming application is a phone? I would like the url to remain the same and also not to have a check within the controller action method for device.

Any way to do the above?

Answer (score 1):

Example post here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2011/02/25/mobile-enabled-web-apps-with-asp-net-mvc-3-and-jquery-mobile.aspx

on redirecting a user to a mobile area of your MVC project using a filter attribute.

Best I can find, I know you said you didn't want to change the URLs.. so maybe you could write a filter attribute to apply to your controller.. so that an action is ignored?

Something like this maybe (not tested) but its nasty since it has to be constantly maintained and is really just injecting more code into your action pipeline which can feel a bit "magic", personally I would go with using separate areas maybe:

```
public class MobileDeviceAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
        {
            if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName == "foo")
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.RedirectToRoute("bar");
        }
    }
}
```